# How to put Tomcat 8 in debug mode with Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I have a sample servlet project in Netbeans 8.0.2. When I right-click my .java (my servlets) and my .html files and choose the "Run-File" option, everything goes as spected: they execute in my server (localhost) with no issues. But when I right-click any of those files and choose "Debug File", I got a dialog flat window in Netbeans that says "Start Server Apache Tomcat (Waiting for Tomcat...)", and it keeps waiting until timeout and fails.

Server is listening in the 8080 port.

This is what I have in the Tomcat Properties (Java Options):

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\logging.properties
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

This is the configuration of the server in Netbeans:
Server Port: 8080, Shutdown port: 8050 ("Enable Http Monitor" option disabled)
Platform: JDK 1.8

username and pw: both "tomcat". This is set in both Netbeans and the tomcat-users.xml file. In my tomcat-users.xml file this is the only one user:

```
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script"/>
```

I stopped Tomcat and ran the `catalina.bat jpda start` command (I'm using Win7 64 SP1 bits) with no luck.

Maybe I'm messing with ports or user permissions.